# How to take the values from the variable and enter in the text box?

Tags: java, list, selenium, random, sendkeys

*titles – is a string variable that contains the string values*

```
List<String> titles = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='document-card__details']//h3/a"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.print("THE NAME ARE " + titles);
```

*below is the x-path of a search box*

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='text-filter__input']//input[@placeholder='Search Title']"));
```

The action I want to perform – To take the random values from the titles[variable] and enter that in the search box.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible. Use java random class.

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < titles.size() ; i++) {
        String titlesItem = titles.get(rand.nextInt(titles.size()));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='text-filter__input']//input[@placeholder='Search Title']")).sendKeys(titlesItem);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int length = 10;
    boolean useLetters = true;
    boolean useNumbers = false;
    List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
    
    titles.forEach(title -> {
        String randomString = RandomStringUtils.random(length, useLetters, useNumbers);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='text-filter__input']//input[@placeholder='Search Title']")).sendKeys(randomString);
    });
```

You can also utilize some alphanumeric strings if required.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

For getting a random title and setting it in input field you can use this:

```
String randomTitle = titles.get(new Random().nextInt(titles.size()));

WebElement searchInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='text-filter__input']//input[@placeholder='Search Title']"));

searchInput.sendKeys(randomTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

To take a random value from `List<String> titles` you have to use *Random()* class and then pass it within the element using `sendKeys()` you can use the following solution:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

List<String> titles = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='document-card__details']//h3/a"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList());
String name = titles.get(new Random().nextInt(titles.size()));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='text-filter__input']//input[@placeholder='Search Title']")).sendKeys(name);
```

Optimizing your code:

```
List<String> titles = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='document-card__details']//h3/a"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='text-filter__input']//input[@placeholder='Search Title']")).sendKeys(titles.get(new Random().nextInt(titles.size())));
```